# Index path for Multiple Dynamic prototype cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, nsindexpath

Gents,

I need some help here. It's almost like I know what I'm trying to do but I've been unable to get it work when coding it out. The scenario is I have a view controller with a table view in it. My table view has three different dynamic prototypes, since I have three different kinds of cells. Now, all I want to do, is to specify which prototype cell to generate in which row. I have also given each of the prototype cells unique identifiers in storyboard.

The way I understand things is that my cellforRowatIndexpath methods needs to understand which kind of cell to display in that row, and then select the identifier as such, dequeue and set the content as required.

Correspondingly, This is my code what I'm trying to do:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   * )indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HelloCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        // configure your cell here...

        return cell;
    }
}
```

---

Unfortunately, things don't work as planned and my app crashed giving me a 
2013-02-07 16:47:39.859 ProjectsABC30068:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x83812e0' error.

There are no issues with the table view as such since I've set the datasource and delegate properly. And also made an outlet for the table view.

I've also tried to change the if statement in cellforRowAtIndexPath to if(myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow==0). This produces the dynamic prototype in all the cells but at least the app doesn't cease.

What do you guys think is the problem?

I don't know how to correctly use index path, if someone could help me with that, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Where are you calling : `setTableViewStyle` ? Or where are you crashing (you can set an exception break point to find out)

Comment: Wait, what is an exception break point and how do I set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it's reporting:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x83812e0

You get this when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not returning a valid `UITableViewCell`.

What value did you return from `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`? The reason I ask is that your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will fail for any row except the first one. If your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` indicated a value greater than 1, then your app will crash.

To confirm this, you might want to examine what `indexPath` is at the the start of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, by adding this line at the start of the method:

```
NSLog(@"%s: section = %d; row = %d", __FUNCTION__, indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
```

That way you can make sure what rows you're trying to generate a cell for and that you're correctly handling it.

Later you say:

> I've also tried to change the if statement in cellforRowAtIndexPath to if(myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow==0). This produces the dynamic prototype in all the cells but at least the app doesn't cease.

That definitely isn't going to work and it implies a confusion of how `cellForRowAtIndexPath` works. It has nothing to do with currently selected cells. You respond to `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` by telling it which cells your are able to create, and iOS will then call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` repeatedly for each of the cells it determines might be visible given the number of sections and number of rows.

Make sure that your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods only return values that you correctly handle in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

---

For further reading, I'd suggest you go through the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) or google "UITableView tutorial".

Comment: This is what I get with the NS Log statement: tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: section = 0; row = 0

Actually, I'm not getting an error now, the application just pauses and I get a message saying Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x310cc493) and on the left pane, Thread 1 0 obc_autorelease is selected

Comment: @DavidWest Both this and the original error message are just different manifestations of the exact same problem. You're not returning a valid `UITableViewCell` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Put a `NSLog` for the `cell` and I bet you'll see it's `nil`. Did you alter your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when you pasted it here, because what you've got listed here is clearly not valid (no closing quote after `HelloCell`). I want to make sure we're looking at the real thing. Also, you make sure that your "Identifier" for your cell in IB is `HelloCell`.

Comment: The quote was just a typo. The identifier is correct. This is the code, I have currently:


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

  if(settingsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow==0)
{
  
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HelloCell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  
  
  
  return cell;
  
    }
}

}

Comment: @DavidWest It just doesn't make sense. First, if you have a prototype with the right identifier, the `dequeue` method should never be `nil`. Second, even if you had a typo (e.g. wrong case, etc.), you're checking for `nil` and creating one if it failed. That's why I was going down the path of wondering if `numberOfRowsForSection` might not have been returning 1, because `indexPath.row > 0` was the only path that I imagined causing the problem you describe. At this point I can only suggest that you compress your project into a zip file and upload it somewhere for us to take a look at it.

Answer (score 7):

With Storyboard and Dynamic prototype cells, you don't have to worry about or check if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns a nil cell.

What you have to do:

- For each row, determine the correct cell identifier and feed that to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`
- For each dynamic prototype cell, make sure you setup the correct identifier (select each cell on the storyboard, then in Attributes Inspector under Table View Cell section fill Identifier)

[image: set up cell identifier]

Let's have an example. Say you have three prototype cells, with identifier as 'Cell1', 'Cell2' and 'Cell3'. And assume you have three rows, each to display with one of the prototype cells.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row + 1];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = identifier; // just show the identifier as title
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(This was a little long to be left as a comment so I've put it here even if it doesn't directly answer the question)

Exception BreakPoint :
Go to breakpoint navigator
[image: Go to breakpoint navigator]

At the bottom of the navigator you have '+' button
[image: Add a breakpoint]

Then it will add a breakpoint for you to customize, just click done and you are set.
[image: click done to complete]

Now when an exception is thrown you will be brought to the line that have trigger the exception. And most importantly you will be able to see your whole call stack of that moment. Very useful for debugging.

There is a lot more 'funky' stuff that can be done with breakpoint in Xcode since 4.2 (not sure exactly when)